# Rotating an image and then translating it with js buttons

Tags: javascript, css

Rotating the picture and translating it works except, I want the rotated image to be translated. When the MoveUp button is pressed it moves the non rotated original image up.

```
var _pic = document.getElementById("picture");
var _rotation = 0;
var _MoveUp = 0;

function RotateLeft(){
_rotation+= 5;
_pic.style.webkitTransform= "rotate(" + _rotation + "deg)";
_pic.style.Moz-transform="rotate(" + _rotation + "deg)";
_pic.style.ms-transform="rotate(" + _rotation + "deg)";
_pic.style.transform="rotate(" + _rotation + "deg)";
}

function RotateRight(){
_rotation-= 5;
_pic.style.webkitTransform= "rotate(" + _rotation + "deg)";
_pic.style.Moz-transform="rotate(" + _rotation + "deg)";
_pic.style.ms-transform="rotate(" + _rotation + "deg)";
_pic.style.transform="rotate(" + _rotation + "deg)";
}

function MoveUp(){
_MoveUp-= 5;
_pic.style.webkitTransform("t100,100r45t-100,0");
//"translateY(" + "T" + _MoveUp + "px)";
_pic.style.Moz-transform="translateY(" + _MoveUp + "px)";
_pic.style.ms-transform="translateY(" + _MoveUp + "px)";
_pic.style.transform="translateY(" + _MoveUp + "px)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MoveUp()` function overrides the rotation transform. To chain together multiple transforms, you should do (only `style.transform` shown for brevity):

```
_pic.style.transform="translateY(" + _MoveUp + "px) rotate(" + _rotation + "deg)";
```

So basically you concatenate all your transforms into one string and set that as value of `style.transform`.

Comment: Would be nice if you could select my answer as "accepted" if this helped you ;)